# How to send SMS using PHP CURL function

Tags: php, codeigniter, sms

I have an account in a website by which I can send sms to mobile phones. In order to do that at first I need to log in using my id and password and then a page shows up where I put the recipient's  mobile number and then my message and finally hit the button to send the message.

Now one of my friends told me that I can send sms from my own application through this website using PHP Curl function. I didn't have any prior idea about CURL function so I googled it but I couldn't figure out how to do this.   I have checked the HTML code of the login page and the page from where I can send the sms of that website and I am posting it below.

Would you please kindly show me how to send sms using CURL function or any other way.. through this website..

Thanks in Advance :)

Form1

```
 <form name="form" action="/websms/index.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="HTMLForm_formname" value="form">


  <table align="center" size="300" border="0" class="list">
  <tr class="r1">
    <th colspan="3" class="left">
        <label id="label_login_title" for="login_title" class="HTMLForm-label">User  Login</label>

       </th>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">
        <label id="label_mobile_no" for="mobile_no" class="HTMLForm-label">Mobile Number</label>
    </td>

     <td>
        <input type="text" id="mobile_no" name="mobile_no" size="20" maxlength="11" value="" onkeypress="return checkNumberOnly(event)" class="HTMLForm-text"> 
    </td>


   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td align="right" valign="top">
        <label id="label_password" for="password" class="HTMLForm-label">Password</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" class="HTMLForm-password" size="20">
    </td>

    </tr>

       <tr>
         <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  class="button_all_action">
            <input type="hidden" id="submit_login" name="submit_login" value="1">
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Second Form

```
<form name="form" action="javascript:get(document.getElementById('form'));" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="HTMLForm_formname" value="form">


<table align="center" size="450" border="0" class="list">


<tr class="r2">
    <th class="left">
        <label id="label_send_to_no" for="send_to_no" class="HTMLForm-label">To</label>
    </th>
    <td class="left">
        <textarea id="send_to_no" name="send_to_no" class="HTMLForm-textarea" onkeypress="checkValidGPNumner(document.form.send_to_no)" onchange="checkValidGPNumner(document.form.send_to_no)" onkeyup="checkValidGPNumner(document.form.send_to_no)" wrap="soft" style="width:250px;height:50px"></textarea>  

    </td>    
  </tr>

 <tr class="r1">

    <th class="left">
        <label id="label_message" for="message" class="HTMLForm-label">Message</label>
    </th>
    <td class="left">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" class="HTMLForm-textarea" onkeypress="textCounter(document.form.message,document.form.counter_message,160)" onchange="textCounter(document.form.message,document.form.counter_message,160)" onkeyup="textCounter(document.form.message,document.form.counter_message,160)" wrap="soft" style="width:250px;height:130px"></textarea>

       <input type="text" id="counter_message" name="counter_message" size="5" value="" readonly="" class="HTMLForm-text"> <label id="label_char_remain" for="char_remain" class="HTMLForm-label">Character remained</label> 
    </td>

 </tr>

     <tr class="r2">
     <td colspan="2" class="center">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="button_all_action">
        <input type="hidden" id="mid" name="mid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" id="submit_sms" name="submit_sms" value="1">
    </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
   </form>
```

Comment: google it, or ask a more specific question.

Comment: Perhaps this website has a REST or custom HTTP API so that you don't have to do scraping to achieve what you are trying. Very little detail for us to give you any help here. Update your question if you would like more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using Twilio.

First of all you have to download the twilio library for PHP:
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/downloads

Then copy the Services folder in your Server and take in mind the location.

Now you have to create a simple program like the one below, (this is an example an easy php sms sender):

```
<?php //lets say that the name of this php is smsSender.php

$contactname = $_POST['name'];
$contactphone = $_POST['mobile_no'];

$message = $_POST['message'];


require 'Services/Twilio.php';//<<<<<<<<<HERE! make sure the path is ok.

$AccountSid = "AXXXXXX"; // this numbers you can find it in your twilio dashboard
$AuthToken = "TXXXXXXXXX";// also this number .

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

$people = array(
//"4566789903" => "Curious George",
$contactphone => $contactname,
);

foreach ($people as $number => $name) {

$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create("7035960031",$number,
$message);

echo "Sent message to $name";

}
?>
```

So you will need to change in your forms the action like this:

```
<form name="form" action="smsSender.php" method="POST">
```

Note: if you are using a trial account, you will be only able to send to verified numbers in your account, but if you register a phone number (1USD/month) then you can send to any number and without the sandbox message).

IMPORTANT: Curl library must be installed in the php server, if you are using your own server, lets say in UBUNTU, this command will install those libraries: 
**sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl**

Comment: Haven't tested your solution but I think it will work, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Simple CURL Function to send sms:

```
    function CURLsendsms($number, $message_body){   

        $api_params = $api_element.'?apikey='.$apikey.'&sender='.$sender.'&to='.$mobileno.'&message='.$textmessage;  
        $smsGatewayUrl = "http://springedge.com";  
        $smsgatewaydata = $smsGatewayUrl.$api_params;
        $url = $smsgatewaydata;

        $ch = curl_init();                       // initialize CURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);    // Set CURL Post Data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);                         // Close CURL

        // Use file get contents when CURL is not installed on server.
        if(!$output){
           $output =  file_get_contents($smsgatewaydata);  
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use urlencode($msg) If you have spaces in between text message.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed send SMS messages with cURL, but cURL is just one part of it. Using cURL, you'd make API calls to a provider like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).

Answer (score 0):

After changing to this, the code worked great for me.

```
foreach ($people as $number => $name) {
$client->account->messages->sendMessage("+12055xxxxxx",$number,
$message);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure that you can send SMS's with CURL, however you can with PHP's mail function.
I have never done so however.

Comment: You can't send sms text messages with curl or mail. You use curl to contact an API which sends the message to you, or use mail to send an email to a service which forwards the content to the recipient. It all depends what implementation the gateway provider has.

Comment: Actually you can use PHP mail.
As you said, you use mail. You send the mail to the sms gateway, something like mobilenum@provider or however is appropriate for the sms gateway as you stated above.
How can you say you can not use mail, but you CAN use mail?

Comment: No. If you don't have proper access to a gateway which allows you to forward emails as a text message, then it doesn't matter how many mails you send - it won't show up as a sms text message on any device. With your reasoning, anything could send a text message. _My spoon can send a text message, because if I press the 'Send' button with my spoon, the spoon actually send the message!_

Comment: If you don't have proper access to the gateway, then I guess you won't be sending mail to it then, will you now?With my reasoning, I do not see how spoons come with PHP, let alone PHP mail!As I have said. You can use PHP mail to send a text message via an sms gateway. If you do not have access to a gateway then you can not send via a gateway. And spoons don't usually come with access to PHP mail functions to use to send mail to the gateway, should they have access.

Comment: This discussion is pointless. cURL doesn't come with PHP access either (which isn't even the point), but is a much more efficient way of contacting a gateway; but cURL alone can't send text messages either. This again validates the point I made in my first comment. EOD for my part.

Answer (score -3):

Curl basically used for scrapping contents from another web site, it doesnt have any function to send sms. You have to use  other way.

there re few tools by which you can connect to your sms (text Server) from there you can send sms. you can use curl to get your sms replies or etc later part if you need and eager to use that.

Comment: Curl is for sending HTTP requests to a HTTP Server.