# How to generate an OTP and send to user in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, one-time-password

I have an API project in codeigniter using  Phil Sturgeon restful server (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver), I need to generate OTP and sent it to users mobile,email while anyone registering to the app, if user submits the correct OTP then only the registration process will complete.

Comment: you need to have a sms services in your application, and inject during when user registration process. you may refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954158/how-to-send-sms-using-php-curl-function

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use string hepler to random OTP

```
$this->load->helper('string');
$otp = random_string('alnum', 6);
// add user info and $otp into database
// send $otp to user
// check the $otp user enter and update user status to actived
```

more info about string helper in CI https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html